# How to upload files in sites/all folder in a hosted website?

Tags: 6, files

I want to edit some `php` files present in `sites/all/themes/danland/` and add some `css` and `js` files in same location. I have checked by modifying in the localhost to see the affect and finally want these changes to appear on the hosted website.

How can do that? I currently have the site login user details of `aws.amazon.com`, `ssh` access to the remote system from where I copied the zipped website files from to work on localhost.

I have already tried to `scp` my required files in the desired file location on the remote system but those php files do not get hosted even after copying. Also, I also do not want to migrate the complete site at once since my changes are minor and I do not want to take the risk of the hosted website gone wrong.

Please help me as I am new to drupal 6.

Comment: You can't copy them maybe it is because of permission. There are two options: 1- the permission is not 777 so you can't copy them 2- when you were moving your site from local to the remote server the files were read only that's why you can't replace them not. try to opening them through CPanel and edit those files to see the effects

Comment: Have a look at deploying sites with Drush, it makes that a lot easier for your type of use case there e.g: drush help site-alias drush help rsync drush help sql-sync More info: https://drupal.org/node/670460

Comment: I was able to copy it to the remote system but it does not get hosted on the website automatically. What additionally is needed to be done to get it hosted?

Comment: If by "to get it hosted" do you mean that you don't see the changes? Have you cleared the cache (Admin, Configuration, Performance)?

Comment: I added a .js file and when I try to open it by giving the correct path location on the internet, the result is "page not found" while if I open other .js files already there on the website, they open. I have used "flush all caches" too as suggested but to no avail.